# Pulling in a playlist from Spotify in JSON Format with JS

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

Is it possible to pull a specific playlist from Spotify with JS and return the playlist in JSON/XML format?

I have looked at the Spotify Developer portal but it seem's as though all they have are widgets.

Is it possible through Echonest or some other service?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no Web API to do this. If you're running inside a Spotify App or a native libSpotify application you can get playlist details then convert it to JSON yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Update from the future: there is a web API to do this: https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-playlist/